# selecting a row using multiple where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my code and the following code is written in .cs page of ASP.net

```
public DataTable SearchSubject(string Branch, string Course, string Year, string Semester)
{
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
    da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from Subjects where Course='" + Course + "' AND Branch='" + Branch + "' AND Year='" + Year + "' AND Semester='" + Semester + "'";
    da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from Subjects where Course= @Course AND Branch= @Branch AND Year= @Year AND Semester= @Semester";
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Course", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Course;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Branch", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Branch;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Year;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Semester", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Semester;
    da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
    da.Fill(ds, "Subjects");
    return ds.Tables["Subjects"];
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: At this point, that is all good.  But you aren't really searching anything at this point, because no controls are present for input.

Comment: There's no actual question present, but you should use the second CommandText and get rid of the first. The first one is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: there is a table of subjects in which on the basis of course, branch, year and semester i am trying to call the subjects from that row. another thing is that when all of there (course, branch, year and semester) columns are true then that one row will be selected and subjects are visible in the dropdown list.